# Azure WebApp - Unable to auto-detect the runtime stack of your app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to create Web App which is just having a Static HTML. I'm following this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-html. But when I execute the following command

> az webapp up --location westeurope --name .

Got the error - " Could not auto-detect the runtime stack of your app" .

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction between the quickstart and [the documentation](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/AzWebAppUP/runtime_detection.md) which does not list static html as being supported. You will probably have more luck reporting this in the Feedback section of the Quickstart.

Comment: I have posted this in the Feedback section. Got to know that It is a known problem. Github link for the reference: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/43633

Answer (score 5):

I tried the following, but added the --html flag at the end of the az webapp up command to bypass auto detection:

```
mkdir quickstart
cd quickstart
git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/html-docs-hello-world.git
cd html-docs-hello-world
az webapp up --location westeurope --name azurewebapptest123 --html
```

That forces HTML. In the help for the command it implies auto-detection works for a bunch of language, but not for static HTML.

Comment: Funny thing is, in the section where the app is first updated, the --html flag is included in the command.

Comment: That is totally right. I wrote my answer and then I saw yours. Your answer should be the solution for this question.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried following the steps mentioned in the documentation. Works for me.

```
mkdir quickstart
cd quickstart
git clone https://github.com/Azure-Samples/html-docs-hello-world.git
cd html-docs-hello-world
az webapp up --location westeurope --name azurewebapptest123
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the similar steps using the sample repo and was able to reproduce it.

[image]

Here is the version:

[image]

It's a known bug for Azure CLI 2.0.78 and team is working on it, Which you can track it here:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/43633

Work around of this issue is to use the older version of Azure CLi e.g. 2.0.75 * for deploying the solution.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

To overcome this error you will need to:

```
cd {directory}
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

The file does not need to have anything just needs to exist as azure looks for the files presence when running the deployment

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually include a web.config file and/or select the stack on General Settings:

[image]

If you have no backend, the best option to host a static site is through Azure Storage:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website

Comment: Yeah, luckily my web site does not have any back-end. So hosted as static site through the Azure Storage

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by using the flag `--html` to define explicitly the runtime according to the documentation of the runtime detection. https://github.com/Azure/app-service-linux-docs/blob/master/AzWebAppUP/runtime_detection.md

So, the solution is the following line of code:

```
az webapp up --location westeurope --name <name> --html
```

N.B: I used Azure cloud shell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're running the command "**az webapp up --location westeurope --name**"  from your application root, ie inside 'html-docs-hello-world' folder.

Answer (score 0):

at end of az webapp command you have give run time stack
if you are using an html page then --html you must give

Ex: az webapp up --location westeurope --name az204samplewebapphtml1 --html