# `az webapp up` no longer works from dotnet publish directory

Tags: asp.net, azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

I'm trying to deploy the contents of a dotnet project after running `dotnet publish`, but the newer versions of `azure-cli` complain with the following error message:

```
$ az webapp up --name MyAppService
Could not auto-detect the runtime stack of your app, see 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2109470' for more information
```

Following the link, https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2109470, I can see that it's looking for a *.csproj file, but that doesn't make sense to me, since I'm deploying files from my publish directory. From what I can see, if I run it from the directory that contains a *.csproj file it works, but tries to zip and upload all the source code and not just the published files.

It originally worked in `azure-cli` v2.0.66. Recently I downgraded to v2.0.75 (as indicated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59529584) and it works also, but I would like to keep `azure-cli` up to date. I've also seen that the `azure-cli` has added an `--html` flag to deploy static files, but my situation is a bit different.

So the question is: How do I get `az webapp up` to work from the `dotnet publish` directory in versions of `azure-cli` >v2.0.75?

Comment: If you copy the csproj to the directory it works for me. –

Answer (score 1):

I think that there is some related bug.

I had a similar issue. Following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/learn/modules/host-a-web-app-with-azure-app-service/index) the final step was apply the `az webapp up` command but the deployed site only had a message saying *"You do not have permission to view this directory or page"*. That means that no site was detected on the deployed site folder.

I applied the `dotnet publish` command and tried to run `az webapp run` from the published folder but the result was the same as you: *"Could not auto-detect the runtime stack of your app, see 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2109470' for more information."*

Finally, from the **root project folder** I ran `dotnet publish -o .` and then `az webapp up` and got the deployment working as expected. This sounds really crazy because I finally got merged the published files with the source code.

This is my first attemp to use `az webapp up`, I hope that this issue to be solved soon.

Comment: so you're telling me that you're deploying the source code along with the .dlls?

Comment: From the azure [documentation](https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/cli/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-up) it's seems that the objective of the command is to deploy the **source code** and compile it automatically to generate de dlls.


`az webapp up: Create and deploy existing local code to the web app, by running the command from the folder where the code is present. [...]`


I think that the issue is ocasionated because the code is not being compiled automatically. I don't know if the behavior of the command was different on previous versions.

Comment: ah ok, so I'll give it a try. I think deploying from the publish folder was an older workflow

Comment: Once you deploy the source code, who compiles it? Does Azure spin up a build environment to do it? BTW we tried the `az webapp up` command without first running `dotnet publish -o`. It failed maybe because it was indeed trying to upload our source code and it may have been too big (see my response comment to the other answer for details).

Comment: I know it's 2 years later, but I'm facing this same issue with dotnet 6. 

Anyway, the reason why this kind of worked is because you set the publish output folder to the current folder "-o .", so locally you now have code and compiled version in the same folder. Then you say "az webapp up" and it copies everything in the current folder. It succeeds because it can find your .csproj file in the current folder.

What I'm doing for now is just to copy the .csproj file to my publish output folder and then run "az webapp up" and it succeeds. Not ideal, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to upgrade the CLI version to 2.0.79 and see if that helps. We recently had issues with Az webapp up and this was fixed by 2.0.79 version.

Please take a look at this thread for more info : [Github Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/44124)

Also this doc for more reference : [Create a static web app in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-html)

Comment: Last version I tried was v2.0.80 and it didn't work either. Are you suggestion that I just use the `--html` flag?

Comment: Hello @ahong, Did it help resolve your issue with the solution that Fernando has provided? If so please accept it as answer so it can beneficial to the community.

Comment: And if you are still having problems, 
We would need you to send us an email at AzCommunity@Microsoft.com by providing below details.
 
Subject : ATTN:Monika 

1) Subscription ID 

2) A link to this thread.

3) Provide the directory content where you are running this cmd.

Please email us these details and we will work with you closely to get this issue taken care of and also post any findings here in the thread so the community can benefit from it. 

Thanks in advance. Looking forward for your email.

Comment: We tried it from the "src" folder with version 2.0.80 and got this error "Deployment endpoint responded with status code 500." It does not look like `az webapp up` runs `dotnet publish` on it's own and looks like it's just uploading the source code. Maybe the 500 is due to the fact it may be uploading a zip of all the source code and may be too large.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the following command from your project directory (where you have your **.csproj** file):

```
dotnet publish
```

Then execute the following command from your **publish** directory (where you have the output files generated by the previous `dotnet publish` command):

```
az webapp up --name <AppServiceName> --runtime <desired_runtime> --os-type <Windows|Linux>
```

Note: you can check the list of available runtimes with `az webapp list-runtimes`

If the `az webapp up` command fails, check in your Azure Web Portal for your App Service if you have the following **Application Settings** parameter:

```
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT
```

If it is present, set its value to `False`, make sure to **Save** its new value, and then try again the `az webapp up` complete command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using one of the newer dotnet (7, 8, etc). You need to specify the `--runtime`

For example

```
# build and create output files
dotnet publish

# go to the published folder
cd bin\Debug\net7.0\publish

# deploy. Make sure you use the --runtime param!
az webapp up --name myapp --os-type windows --runtime dotnet:7
```

That worked for me.

If you dont know what runtimes are supported. You can run the `list-runtimes` command:

```
> az webapp list-runtimes --os windows
[
  "dotnet:8",
  "dotnet:7",
  "dotnet:6",
  "ASPNET:V4.8",
  "ASPNET:V3.5",
  "NODE:18LTS",
  "NODE:16LTS",
  "java:1.8:Java SE:8",
  "java:11:Java SE:11",
  "java:17:Java SE:17",
  "java:1.8:TOMCAT:10.0",
  "java:11:TOMCAT:10.0",
  "java:17:TOMCAT:10.0",
  "java:1.8:TOMCAT:9.0",
  "java:11:TOMCAT:9.0",
  "java:17:TOMCAT:9.0",
  "java:1.8:TOMCAT:8.5",
  "java:11:TOMCAT:8.5",
  "java:17:TOMCAT:8.5"
]
```